# Is it possible to get back the jupyter editing when my browser(chrome) crashes?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, jupyter-notebook

I was doing some job using jupyter notebook. The jupyter server is set up in a remote server, and I visit the jupyter notebook using the browser (chrome) in my Macbook. However, I lost the editing since the last checkpoint because of the crash of chrome. In detail, I didn't save the editing last time I sleep my Macbook, and when I awake it, I find that  chrome crashes and all the pages I opened lost.

I have visited 'chrome://cache', but found nothing. Sad!

I'm wondering if there is a way to get back my editing of jupyter notebook back. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If Chrome crashed with unsaved changes they are probably lost. I have seen cases where Chrome crashes and saves some things. If you go under History there might be recently closed tabs which you can recover. If that doesn't work I'm afraid you have probably lost your changes. If this is a common issue you run into you might want to consider [increasing your autosave frequency](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/03/change-default-autosave-interval-in-ipython-notebook/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I waked my Macbook, Chrome reminded me of the recovery of lost pages. However, the jupyter editing pages were gone and could not be recovered. I think that I  have lost my editing forever. I think that it is necessary to increase the autosave frequency, which helps to reduce the  lost.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround to recover most of the changes I did since the last checkout - by simply calling this command in your notebook:

```
%history -g
```

If you want your IPython history in a plain-text file, you can export it yourself.

You can also do it for a specific filename:

```
%history -g -f filename
```

What does -g do? – Without -g it exports the history for the current session. With -g it exports history for all sessions.